# How to loop/restart a perl script?

Tags: perl, loops, whois

I have made a simple whois script that returns back the whois information of a domain. Once it's done it returns back to the original terminal, example below.

```
user@ubuntu:; perl script.pl
Enter domain name: name.com
etc... whois information displays here.
user@ubuntu:;
```

At the end the "user@ubuntu" returns, how do I get it to go back to the start?

I want to loop it.

Comment: Is that different from just running it again?

Comment: Are you asking how to do loops in perl/bash?

Answer (score 1):

In perl,

```
while ( 1 )
{
    print "Enter domain name: ";
    my $domain = <>;
    last unless $domain && $domain =~ /\w/;
    domain =~ s/\s+//g;         #super-chomp is good idea
    your code here...
}
```

Used a two-stage unless in case EOF produces undef as I don't want undef =~ /\w/ to produce run-time warnings on aggressive warning levels.

Answer (score 0):

in bash you can do:

```
while [ /bin/true ]
do
    perl script.pl
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: while(1){
# Your current code here #
}

That was what I was looking for.